# React native - issues with async await

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I have 2 function calls:

```
const result = _checkPermissions();
if (result === 'granted') {
    this._googleSignIn();
}
```

I want `_checkPermissions()` to return before I run the if statement.....however I cant seem to do this and code just continues on to if statement before `_checkPermissions()` has returned.

I know its got something to do with async await but i cant figure it out

Below is code for `_checkPermissions()`

```
export const _checkPermissions = async () => {
  const result = await check(
    Platform.select({
      android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      ios: PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE,
    }),
  );
  switch (result) {
    case 'blocked':
      return 'blocked';
    case 'granted':
      return 'granted';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to await `_checkPermissions`. Since `_checkPermissions` is an `async` function it returns a promise which resolves/rejects at a later point of time. You can use await with the promise or you can write inside the `.then` block of promise.

Promise approach:

```
const result = await _checkPermissions();
if (result === 'granted') {
    this._googleSignIn();
}
```

- If you are using `await` you need to add `async` to the parent function.*

`.then` approach:

```
_checkPermissions().then(result => {
    if (result === 'granted') {
        this._googleSignIn();
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You still need to put await in front of _checkPermissions();

```js
const result = await _checkPermissions();
if (result === 'granted') {
    this._googleSignIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

although adding await is the perfect option , but in case you dont get the required result then you can use setInterval
under if result == 'granted'

```
if (result === 'granted') {
    setInterval(() => {
       this._googleSignIn();
    },2000)
}
```

your `this._googleSignIn();` will run after 2 seconds till then your promise will be resolved .... this is just a trick better answer is to use await .